# Login form prepared statements not functioning

Tags: php, forms, authentication, prepared-statement

I'm making a login form with prepared statements, I already have a register form where that data is in a database. Now my login form is not returning "Hello, you are logged in". I double checked all the variables matching my in my db and code, local host is correct, html is fine. Thanks

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$Email = $Password = "";
$Email_err = $Password_err = "";
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if Email is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["Email"]))){
        $Email_err = 'Please enter Email.';
    } else{
        $Email = trim($_POST["Email"]);
    }

    // Check if Password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST['Password']))){
        $Password_err = 'Please enter your Password.';
    } else{
        $Password = trim($_POST['Password']);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($Email_err) && empty($Password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT Email, Password FROM people WHERE Email = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters

            $param_Email = $Email;
            // Set parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_Email);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if Email exists, if yes then verify Password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $Email, $hashed_Password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(Password_verify($Password, $hashed_Password)){
                            /* Password is correct, so start a new session and
                            save the Email to the session */
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
                            echo "Hello! You are signed in!";
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if Password is not valid
                            $Password_err = 'The Password you entered was not valid.';
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if Email doesn't exist
                    $Email_err = 'No account found with that Email.';
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it giving any errors? Or just not showing anything

Comment: It just takes me to a blank page, no errors or notices.

Comment: Been looking at it for hours...